# The Calendar.set(field,value) doesn't set the hour properly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-calendar

I'm using 2 different dialog Picker, 1 for Date and one for the Hour in an android app.
Once the user confirm the values selected in the dialog i use them to update the variable `Calendar cal` using the function  `cal.set()` . But when i try to get the time after setting it using `cal.getTime()` the output isn't consistent. i.e. if i select 6:00 from the picker and updete my cal sometimes the hour output is 18:00 and sometimes is 6:00. Another strange thing that i don't understand at all is that even if i don't change the actual DAY field, swapping between the 6 A.M(6) and 6 P.M (18) sometimes increase the DAY count.
Testing i'v seen that the values from the timePicker are exactly the ones that i click on them.
The `cal` variable is private and it's declared in the same activity class as the fallowing code.
The calendar is instantied in 2 different ways depending on the intent that opened the app, in one case i get the current time `cal = Calendar.getInstance();`  otherwise after i getInstance() i setup is using `cal.setTime(date);`

```
 timeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int inputHH, int inputMM) {

            Log.d("Output picker hour ",String.valueOf(inputHH));
            Log.d("Output picker minutes ",String.valueOf(inputMM));
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, inputMM);
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, inputHH);
            Log.d("calendar hour", cal.getTime().toString());
            timeView.setText(hourFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

        }
```

This is my console ouput during the test

```
D/Output picker hour: 6
D/Output picker minutes: 0
D/calendar hour: Sun Jun 07 18:00:50 GMT+02:00 2020
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72f466c900 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x730f4f84e0
D/Output picker hour: 18
D/Output picker minutes: 0
D/calendar hour: Mon Jun 08 06:00:50 GMT+02:00 2020
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72f5734100 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x72f4ee58e0
D/Output picker hour: 6
D/Output picker minutes: 0
D/calendar hour: Mon Jun 08 06:00:50 GMT+02:00 2020
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72f5537a00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x72f47bc4a0
D/Output picker hour: 6
D/Output picker minutes: 0
D/calendar hour: Mon Jun 08 06:00:50 GMT+02:00 2020
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72f5596100 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x72f5fec360
D/Output picker hour: 18
D/Output picker minutes: 0
D/calendar hour: Mon Jun 08 18:00:50 GMT+02:00 2020
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72f4248400 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x72f467afa0
D/Output picker hour: 18
D/Output picker minutes: 0
D/calendar hour: Tue Jun 09 06:00:50 GMT+02:00 2020
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x72f42f4700 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x72f56b33c0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, inputHH);`

instead

`cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, inputHH);`

Comment: Thank you vary much this fixed the problem!!
Can you explain me the different between the HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY field ?

Comment: HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock.
If the answer was correct, you can accept my answer